# Ruby Application using When/Case yielding Nil when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, switch-statement, compare, equality

The following code should print one of the three options given depending on the results of any of the `==` checks, but it doesn't. It yields `nil` for any value of *your_message* provided via `gets.chomp`. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```rb
def stupid_coach(your_message)
  case your_message
  when your_message == your_message.include?("?")
    p "Silly question, get dressed and go to work!"
  when !your_message == your_message.include?("?")
    p "I don't care, get dressed and go to work!"
  when your_message == "I am going to work now!"
    exit
  end
end
```

Comment: So you want to check whether the contents of `your_message` is equal to a `true` or `false` value? I think you need to go back and reread documentation on [`.include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) and on [`case`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression).

Comment: Hi pjs...thank you for your feedback. Besides reading the documentation, I would like to have a dialogue with my seniors/peers to understand the error or mistake...I know how include and case work, what I dont know is why, in my current context, the code is not operating as intended. Any thoughts?. Thanks.

Comment: "I know how include and case work". Sorry, but that's clearly not true. Hence my suggestion to review the documentation.

Comment: Big hint: if you know that `.include?` returns either `true` or `false`, fire up your choice of `irb` or `pry` and see what happens when you enter `"some string" == true` or `"some string" == false`. Then try it using `===`. You should see why your `case` statement never produces a match.

Comment: The explicit returns in your edit are unnecessary. On a separate note, it's considered bad SO etiquette to fundamentally change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. The right thing to do is usually to open a related question that links back to the original if you have separate follow-on questions.

Comment: If [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883155/ruby-application-using-when-case-yielding-nil-when-it-shouldnt#comment133850144_75883999) doesn't clarify your follow-up changes sufficiently--I think it does, but your mileage may vary--then please open a new question about how to perform the additional comparison you want within a case expression, and maybe receive a better explanation than can fit in comments about why that comparison doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Hi Todd, many thanks for your valuable comment...I managed to make it work. Your statement is absolutely correct....the issue was the order of my checks...that was key. And of course, the fact that I was previously comparing a string against a boolean...many thanks for your strong and patient support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Case Expressions and Threequals

A [case expression](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) doesn't work the way you seem to think. It's not just another way to express if/then conditions. Under the hood, case implements the `===` operator on an expression when passed an argument to case, or allows you to use it like a set of if-statements if you *don't* pass the initial argument. It also does pattern matching, but that's out of scope for this question.

#### Dropping the Argument to Your Control Expression

When you provide an argument to case, such as `case your_message` then each when-statement will be evaluated as an *expression* against the argument using class-specific threequals rather than the conditional you think you're giving it. This is easily fixed by dropping the argument to case. For example:

```rb
your_message = "foo?"

case
when your_message.end_with?("?")
  "bar"
end

#=> "bar"
```

Now, instead of effectively saying `"foo?" === true` (which obviously will return `false`) Ruby simply evaluates whether the when-statement is truthy or not. Based on your existing code, this is probably the easiest way to get the behavior you expect.

#### Using a Proc, Lambda, or Regexp with Threequals

Alternatively, you can restructure your case statement to use procs, lambdas, or even regular expressions that can match a threequal comparison because it's implemented by the class. For example, consider the following example that leverages [Proc#===](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) to compare the results of a lambda.

```rb
your_message = "foo? \n"

case your_message
when ->{ _1.strip.end_with? "?" }
  "baz"
end

#=> "baz"
```

This basically passes the argument to case (e.g. *your_message*) into a lambda, where you can then call methods on the argument to evaluate its truthiness. It's a more complex approach, but can be useful.

Since [regular expressions also support a threequals method](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), you can use those too:

```rb
your_message = "foo?"

case your_message
when /\?$/
  "quux"
end

#=> "quux"
```

### Other Issues with Your Code

You should also consider things like order dependency. In your example code, even if there weren't other issues, `"I am going to work now!"` would never get matched because the previous when-statements (if working) would return a value based on the presence or absence of a question mark before you ever reached that particular comparison. Case expressions don't "fall through" the way they do in other languages, so you need to take statement precedence into account the same way you would in an if/elsif/else/end control expression.

#### A Working Example

The following is a lot simpler, and works fine. It returns valid results, and won't return nil. It *does* assume that *your_message* can #respond_to?(:strip) though, but you can tweak the code further if you like.

```rb
def stupid_coach your_message
    case your_message.strip
    when "I am going to work now!"
      "This works when checked before matching for '?'."
    when /\?$/
      "Silly question, get dressed and go to work!"
    else
      "I don't care, get dressed and go to work!"
    end 
end
```

You can test it against an array of sample inputs. The results seem valid to me, but you can certainly exercise it against other String values if you think there's a corner case.

```rb
["Foo?", "Bar.", "I am going to work now!"]
  .map { stupid_coach _1 }

#=> 
["Silly question, get dressed and go to work!",
 "I don't care, get dressed and go to work!",
 "This can match if checked before mactching for '?'."]
```

The order in which you execute the samples doesn't matter. If you reorder the test array you still get the correct results. As long as the order of your when-statements is correct, and you're using the correct type of expression for the comparisons, you can get the case expression to do what you want—just not necessarily in the way you were originally expecting.

Comment: Hi Todd...your comments are VERY useful, many thanks. I have re-ordered my WHEN cases...however, my "when your_message.upcase && your_message.include?("!")" is not working as expected...basically, it returns the expression when the test string is "test!" which is not correct...it should return the expression ONLY when BOTH conditions are met..this is "TEST!). Any thoughts?. Many thanks,

Comment: @Panamaniac507 You're going to need to open a separate question about this if you want a detailed answer. The short version is that your first expression doesn't return a Boolean. You likely want `when your_message.eql?(your_message.upcase) && your_message.end_with?("!")`, but it's hard to say without seeing the full context. Almost everything in Ruby is an expression so understanding truthiness, precedence, and comparing expressions is essential. You might want to stick with if-statements for this, as they are more aligned with the way you're thinking about your code.

Comment: I recently learned that you can also do the following, which could be useful:

```
case object
when -> (obj) { obj.some_logic }
    blah
when -> (obj) { obj.other_logic }
    blah blah
when -> (obj) { obj.yet_other_logic }
    blah blah blah blah
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `case` expression, the `when` is comparing the value to a value.

In your case, you're comparing `your_message` which is presumably a string, to boolean values.

Consider a very simple example:

```
irb(main):001:1* case "hello"
irb(main):002:1* when true
irb(main):003:1*   puts "foo"
irb(main):004:1* else
irb(main):005:1*   puts "bar"
irb(main):006:0> end
bar
=> nil
```

You could use regular expressions or match against strings.

```
def stupid_coach(your_message)
    case your_message
    when "I am going to work now!"
        exit
    when /\?/
        p "Silly question, get dressed and go to work!"
    else
        p "I don't care, get dressed and go to work!"
    end
end
```

Though I'm not sure you actually want to exit the program the way your code will if it hits `exit`, and the method itself will return `nil`.

If you want it to return the strings rather than printing them:

```
def stupid_coach(your_message)
    case your_message
    when "I am going to work now!"
        exit
    when /\?/
        "Silly question, get dressed and go to work!"
    else
        "I don't care, get dressed and go to work!"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you chaps...I've refined my code as follows but when using the following test strings TEST! and test are not yielding the correct results as per my code...